# efficiently using large arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

i'm working on a program in C that uses 4D arrays with 2 millions+ points. i currently have it implemented like this:

main.h

```
extern float data[31][31][25][100];
```

main.c

```
float data[31][31][25][100] = {{.....},{......},.....}; 

int main()
{
double sum; 

for(i=0;i<31;i++)
for(j=0;j<31;j++)
for(k=0;k<25;k++)
for(l=0;l<100;l++)
  sum += data[i][j][k][l];
}
```

the sum is there as a place holder...in its place will be something that does a 4D lookup table. i implemented like this because i dont want to load this data from disk. in the future i might use a database or something to load just a portion of the data but for now i need to use the whole dataset.

so my question is...is there any way i can so this more efficiently and/or can i make this executable smaller (executable currently is ~5 MB. This will eventually run on a quadcore arm board.

the only other thing i've tried is the optimization with gcc. i've tried -O2 and -O4 and i've gotten the following error. Without -O2, it compiles and runs fine. any ideas? i havent really looked up what all the optimization options are...just tried stuff i've seen online.

```
ld: can't link with a main executable file 'test' for architecture x86_64
```

thanks for your help!

**answers to comments:**

1. the data cannot be generated programmatically. the data is generated
   by offline simulation
2. i've updated to code to show that the array is outside of the main and is global
3. @js1 you're right its closer to 9 MB, i was working with couple versions of the code and the 5 MB executable was one with 1 million+ elements.
4. @pm100 i guess thats a good question...i'm prototyping this code on a pc and it works fine...but where it will actually end up running is on an embedded platform. we are currently planning on testing with a [pixhawk](https://store.3drobotics.com/products/3dr-pixhawk) (which is an arm board for rc vehicles, our production board will be faster and have more memory). i am trying to be efficient and optimal as possible to mitigate any potential issues running on an arm platform.
5. @user3629249 yes we are prototyping our code on mac osx and then
   compiling for ARM once we are finished.
6. @mcleod_ideafix would loading a binary file that contains 2million
   pts be faster? honestly i hadnt even considered a binary file...i
   will try implementing like this. everytime the program is called, it
   will need access to some portion of this data. it wont need all 2
   million pts but the input deciding which part of the array it needs
   is variable. ideally i'd like to load just the portion of the arrays
   that i needed. however when i tried it out, loading the file and
   searching for the right arrays took 2-3x longer than this current
   approach. i wonder if i messed something up when i was
   loading/searching the file.

**answers to comments pt2:**
the data isnt sparse...i cant think of any easy ways to reduce the number of pts without reducing the fidelity of the model. the data is fixed and wont ever change. what will change are the inputs to use the data, which will lead to different portions of the 4D data being used.

as far as what the data is: it is essentially trajectory prediction data for flying vehicle. the 4D data is generated offline using a nonlinear simulation running on a cluster.
so what my embedded program has to do is take the current vehicle state (location, orientation, etc.) along with the 4D data to generate a estimated trajectory. i cant really provide the dataset due to proprietary reasons. i hope this answers some questions...sorry for being vague

i will work on a binary implementation and try loading a subset of the array. i might have done something dumb that made it really slow. thank you all for the comments, it gave me some new ideas to try out.

Comment: Can you procedurally generate the contents of `data` instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: The odds of you overloading your double is crazy high , even if we are dealing with numbers like 5.

Comment: I'm not too knowledgeable on this, but maybe consider a 4D to 1D mapping function and then using a 1D array. Also consider using your architecture's SIMD instructions.

Comment: How is your executable only 5MB when your array is 9MB+ in size (assuming 32-bit floats)?  In any case, you could store your data in a zipped (or other compressed) format and use a library function to decompress the data.  I'm assuming here that the data will be highly compressible.

Comment: @JS1 The likely answer would be that the system uses [half-precision floating-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format), with only 16 bits per float. (Expected size is a little over 4.8 MB)

Comment: It's not clear from your posted code whether `float data[31][31][25][100]` is  inside `main` function or outside it.

Comment: strongly suggest the array be outside of any function, as placing a 5 (or 9) meg item on the stack is almost certain to overflow the stack size.  It seems your using the wrong compiler as the error message indicates an x86-64 architecture and not an ARM architecture.

Comment: whats not efficient about it now? speed, I doubt it - this will be very fast. size? 9 mb array is small on modern systems

Comment: I very strongly doubt that your code actually contains  a couple million entries where your initializing the array.    Could you post code that actually compiles, so we could examine/debug the problem?

Comment: You could use static float data[...] in main() or make it a global outside main to avoid stack size issues. In terms of load time, either the 8MB(?) of data is included as part of your program, or your program can read it in from a separate file. 8MB isn't that much space from either the heap or from memory. For the specific case of adding up all the numbers, you  could treat the array as a 1D array, and only use 1 iterator, but since the last dimension is 100, this won't make much difference in speed.

Comment: Is it some sparse data (most entries being 0)? Please edit your question to explain what is the data

Comment: The code to load data from the file might have been slower due to how you're loading it, but it's still a lot to load. Is there a way to optimize portions of the data after all of the data is generated, such as ordering it somehow (e.g. instead of `{3, 4, 2, 1}`, use `{1, 2, 3, 4}`), which could help in making random access lookup easier when loading specific data from a file? Is the data fixed or mutable after it's generated? With the number of questions, I'd have to agree with Basile Starynkevitch: we need some context here. What is the data and what will you be doing with it?

Comment: If you can predict the access pattern, and your machine support OOO, then you can write a "touch" function to eliminate cache miss overhead completely. The trick is to use assembly to load from a memory address and discard the loaded value. With OOO, if that "touch" is a cache miss, it will only stall one instruction, which is nothing, and CPU will service this cache miss. Then, later, when your code really needs the data, which is "touched" not long ago, it is guaranteed a cache hit. This is common micro optimization on machine that has OOO but not hardware cache pre-fetching.

Comment: Instead of static data in the program data segment, you could use a memory mapped file and access that via a pointer*.  This would save loading most of the data each time the program is run: only accessed pages would be paged in.  Check `mmap`. (*) The type declaration for such a pointer is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data cannot be generated programatically, then they have to be somewhere in your hard disk when your program starts, and your program, somehow must load that data into the 4D array.

So if your executable is 5MB in size, that is normal considering that the initialization data is included. This approach has the benefit of being the OS which loads and initializes your array. When your program executes the first instruction of your main() function, the data is already there. You have just to use it. The disadvantage is that if your program never needs to use the data, the memory they use will still be there, wasting address space.

On the other hand, you can have your data in a separate file: be it a data file which you will load as part of your processing, be it a dynamic library your program loads when needed, or a binary file you map into memory. The advantage if this is that you load the data into memory only if and when it's needed, needing the extra address space only when you actually access your data, and freeing it when it's no longer needed. Besides, your executable will load faster, as no prior load and initialization will be required. The disadvantage of this is that your program will have to include some procedure to load and initialize the 4D array prior to use it, and some other to dispose it when not needed.

That said, for a static non procedural-calculated values array that needs to live for the entire program, the most efficient way is to declare the array as global and initialize it in the same declaration. This will add a memory block with the initialized data, already in the format needed for the array, in your .data section. The beginning of that memory block will be assigned to the name of your array during the relocation operation.

Comment: At 5 Meg, you would have multiple data segments involved.

Comment: Why? The address space is linear, not segmented

Comment: Yes, and no. This is compiler dependent. With gcc and x86_64, for memory reserved on the stack, you are limited.  Now gcc is smart enough to rearrange the pieces and maximize what it can use to make up the stack (depending on what you initialize), but with the default compile options you will find a maximum of roughly 8M of stack space available. If you declare the maximum int array say, `int max [1447] = {0};` and dump to assembly, you will see that you are actually addressing multiple segments, with any single segment limited to roughly 2M)

Comment: I'm talking about declaring the array as a global variable. Global variables don't reside in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need 32bit floating point precision?
16bit fixed point values would for example cut the size of your binary in half.
If the characteristics of the values stored in the table are linear rather than exponential, then fixed point is the most efficient way to store them in terms of precision per stored bit of information.

Uneven fixed point representations of 24bits or 12bits per value is also a possibility.

You could also consider using different levels of precision for different parts of the table.

Is every single value of the lookup table actually used? Perhaps certain subsections of it can be omitted. It would reduce size at the cost of a more complicated data structure and lookup function.

On a side note, you may want to declare your lookup table to be "const".

Comment: i'm not sure...reducing the precision will affect the accuracy of our output. but it could very well be that 16 bit might be good enough for this. we might be able to tolerate a bit more error for improved performance. we unfortunately we cannot change some parts of the dataset. we have certain performance guarantees that result from the precision of the numbers (i'm not working this aspect so i cant really go into anymore detail). so we want to guarantee a certain metric over the entire envelope.

Comment: More knowledge of the values you need to store would really help us find a solution for you.
What are the maximum and minimum non-zero values, and how many decimals do you need?

16bit fixed point values can for example represent values between 0-1000 with about 2 decimals. Like: 456.78.

You optimize the tradeoff between range and precision to match your needs.

24bit fixed point numbers would reduce your size by 25%, yet provide very good precision.

Answer (score -1):

As far as your lookups go.

I would recommend using Tree's for each of your lists. this will greatly reduce lookup time to (LOG(n)) and insertion time as well at n(log(n)) at most.

That will at least help your application move much faster when operating.

You'll want to use a decent data structure. such as a Heap or generic B-TREE.